# How to fix the size of the window/view in React.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, npx

When I created a React app and ran for the first time, the app view occupies only some part of the screen.

[The section looks half filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV6jE.png)
[This is the size of the html tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk6TI.png)

This is the code of index.js and App.js:

I tried defining the App.css file and used html selector. Then I set the width and height to 100% although it looked like a temporary solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.